# How to join two table with non-existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables

a schema table:

```
ID | ITEM
-----------
01  | i1 
02  | i2 
03  | i3
```

And a record table:

```
RecordID | ITEM | VALUE
---------------------- 
RE001    | i1   | 100  
RE002    | i2   | 102  
RE003    | i1   | 200  
RE003    | i2   | 220
```

I want to get a result table that looks like this

```
RecordID | ITEM | VALUE
 ---------------------- 
RE001    | i1   | 100  
RE001    | i2   | null  
RE001    | i3   | null  
RE002    | i1   | null  
RE002    | i2   | 102 
RE002    | i3   | null  
RE003    | i1   | 200 
RE003    | i2   | 220  
RE003    | i3   | null
```

I tried use `LEFT JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`, those return me a merged row with 
same item that is a null

Is there any methods allow doing such thing?

Comment: have you tried `left outer join` ?

Comment: Yes, it also gives me the merge row for null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you want is this:

```
 select q1.recordid, q2.item, `value`
  from (
    (select distinct recordid 
      from `record`) q1
    cross join
    (select distinct item
      from `schema`) q2
  ) left join `record` r
    on r.recordid = q1.recordid and r.item = q2.item
  order by q1.recordid, q2.item
```

But due to the cross join in the inner queries it could very quickly become a very huge result set.

[Heres the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0f2f/13)

Comment: Thanks men, it really helped :)  and yes it will be a huge set after a will, but i can filter it down by some conditions, the reason for me doing this is to save some rows to store in database.\

Comment: no problem. glad it helped. its honestly the first time i've ever used a cross join for anything other than initialising variables.  if the answer helped, could you please accept it

Comment: @pala_ : Good one. nice